# Just want to print out 2 values from an API response Python

Tags: python

I am calling an API that returns some user data, see output below.

All I want to do is print out 2 of the values from each section labeled node, ultimately I want to use the output in an html table. I have looked at a dozen or more posts on here and can't get this sort of output.

In the case out the output below I would like to print out 2 lines:
`username 1 - email address 1`

`username 2 - email address 2`

```
{
    "data": {
        "organization": {
            "samlIdentityProvider": {
                "externalIdentities": {
                    "edges": [
                        {
                            "node": {
                                "guid": "SOMESTRING 1",
                                "samlIdentity": {
                                    "nameId": "email address 1"
                                },
                                "user": {
                                    "login": "username 1"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "node": {
                                "guid": "SOMESTRING 2",
                                "samlIdentity": {
                                    "nameId": "email address 2"
                                },
                                "user": {
                                    "login": "username 2"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "ssoUrl": "https://ssomeurl.com"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried getting them both from the dictionary with `[]` syntax? Or is there a specific reason you can't do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with the [json](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) module. Parse the nested keys down to the two nodes you want, then print each of their values:

```
import json

data = json.loads(user_data)

for edge in data['data']['organization']['samlIdentityProvider']['externalIdentities']['edges']:
    print edge['node']['user']['login'], edge['node']['samlIdentity']['nameId']
```

This should give you:

```
username 1 email address 1
username 2 email address 2
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for.  Seems so much easier than all the other answers that I was looking at.    Thank you very much

Comment: @smolz very glad I could help